# Rails relation throws an error: SQLException: no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have events, which have speakers and sliders.

class Event

```
  has_many :speakers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :speakers, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :sliders, dependent: :destroy
```

class Speaker

```
 belongs_to :event
```

class Slider

```
 belongs_to :event
```

Speakers do not have their own controller (they are submitted straight to model via nested attributes), sliders do.

When I upload new sliders, I get an error when trying to output them in the event view (the speakers show up nicely):

Event view

```
<% @event.sliders.each do %>
  <p>hello dolly</p>
<% end %>
```

Error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sliders.event_id: SELECT "sliders".* FROM "sliders"  WHERE "sliders"."event_id" = ?
```

Event controller

```
  def show      
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Console:

```
>> e = Event.find_by(id:9)
=> #<Event id: 9, title: "...">

>> e.speakers
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Speaker id: 59, name: "...", created_at: "2013-08-27 09:28:58", updated_at: "2013-08-27 09:28:58", event_id: 9>]>

>> e.sliders
!! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sliders.event_id: SELECT "sliders".* FROM "sliders"  WHERE "sliders"."event_id" = ?>
```

My migrations & schemas are all in place, I guess I'm having troubles with relations?

Thank you Stackoverflow people

Comment: is yours `sliders` table has `event_id` column or any foreign_key ... add it by create a migration in `up` -> `add_column :sliders, :event_id, :integer` in down -> `remove_column :sliders, :event_id` thanks

Comment: @RajarshiDas, suggest adding this as an answer. I didn't see your edits when I posted my answer.

Comment: @vinodadhikary vote you up......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is yours sliders table has `event_id` column or any foreign_key ... add it by generating a migration

`rails generate migration AddEventIdToSliders event_id:integer`

`rake db:migrate`

thanks

Comment: Gosh that was easy! Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Your `sliders` table is missing `event_id` column which is why you are getting that error.  You can run another migration to add `event_id` column to `sliders` table using the following:

```
rails g migration add_event_id_to_sliders event_id:integer
```

Then run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```